# Microblaze Cross Compile

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, xilinx, bare-metal, microblaze

Does anyone know how to use gcc to compile a bare-metal program for xilinx's microblaze processor?

It is very easy to do this with xilinx sdk, but now I am trying to integrate the microblaze build into a larger build workflow.  In other words, I need to be able to do everything command line -- not using the sdk gui.

Most of xilinx support and examples are centered around their sdk.  There seems to be limited support on their site for gnu tools but they seem to be focused on users who want to compile a linux kernel for microblaze.  I just want to compile a simple bare metal application.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like

```
$ gcc microblaze_program.c
```

and end up with a microblaze executable.

Has anyone done this before?  Does anyone know of any examples?

Answer (score 3):

SDK creates a makefile - you can just make use of this from the command line.

If you don't open the command-line from Xilinx's provided icon, you need to call $XILINX/settings[32|64].[bat|sh] to set up the environment correctly first.

Comment: I just installed the SDK standalone package for linux.  Unfortunately, none of the xilinx tools work -- xsdk, xmd, elfcheck, etc all crash, but that is a separate problem.  The good thing is that all the gnu tools work just fine (e.g. mb-gcc, mb-as, etc) so I can just set up the project using sdk on windows, then copy the generated libraries, board support package, linker script, and makefile over to the linux build directory and then just execute 'make all' and it seems to work just fine.